# Comparing two tab delimited files on the basis of first column of the both the files and print matching and non matching entries in output file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have two tab-delimited files(fileA.txt and fileB.txt), I have to compare the first column of fileA.txt with the first column of fileB.txt and also I want to print the values present in the second column of fileB.txt in the output file.
Below is my

`fileA.txt`

```
id
chr1_45796849_A_T
chr1_45796854_C_T
chr1_45797174_T_A
chr1_45796852_G_C
chr19_9018540_A_G
chr19_9002576_T_C
chr1_45797487_A_G
chr1_45797153_A_T
chr1_45797750_C_T
```

`FileB.txt`

```
chr_pos             freq.var
chr1_45796849_A_T   0.028399811
chr1_45796852_G_C   0.019154034
chr1_45796854_C_T   0.015872901
chr1_45797153_A_T   0.010129176
chr1_45797487_A_G   0.012981216
chr1_45797750_C_T   0.024949931
```

following is expected outcome

```
id                  freq.var
chr1_45796849_A_T   0.028399811
chr1_45796854_C_T   0.015872901
chr1_45797174_T_A   
chr1_45796852_G_C   0.019154034
chr19_9018540_A_G   
chr19_9002576_T_C   
chr1_45797487_A_G   0.012981216
chr1_45797153_A_T   0.010129176
chr1_45797750_C_T   0.024949931
```

I have referred to [awk - comparing 2 columns of 2 files and print common lines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879754/awk-comparing-2-columns-of-2-files-and-print-common-lines) but it gives only matching entries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read `fileB.txt` first, make the 1st field a key and the 2nd field its value in an array,
skipping the header line with `FNR>1` ([What are NR and FNR and what does "NR==FNR" imply?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32481877)).

Then read `fileA.txt`, print its header for the first line and then print its 1st field followed by the corresponding element in the
array, if any.

```
awk '
    FNR==NR && FNR>1{a[$1]=$2}
    NR!=FNR{
        if(FNR>1){print $1,a[$1]}
        else{print "id", "freq.var"}
    }
' OFS="\t" fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

`OFS="\t"` sets the output field separator to tab. Since your file is tab delimited, I assume the output file should be tab delimited too.

You can pipe that into `column -t` for alignment.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to keep the original sort order, you can use `join`:

```
$ join -a1 -j1 -t$'\t' <(tail -n+2 fileA.txt | sort)  <(tail -n+2 fileB.txt | sort)
chr1_45796849_A_T   0.028399811
chr1_45796852_G_C   0.019154034
chr1_45796854_C_T   0.015872901
chr1_45797153_A_T   0.010129176
chr1_45797174_T_A
chr1_45797487_A_G   0.012981216
chr1_45797750_C_T   0.024949931
chr19_9002576_T_C
chr19_9018540_A_G
```

Or, to keep the headers:

```
$ ( printf 'id\tfreq.var\n'; join -t$'\t' -a1 -j1 <(tail -n+2 fileA.txt | sort)  <(tail -n+2 fileB.txt | sort))
id  freq.var
chr1_45796849_A_T   0.028399811
chr1_45796852_G_C   0.019154034
chr1_45796854_C_T   0.015872901
chr1_45797153_A_T   0.010129176
chr1_45797174_T_A
chr1_45797487_A_G   0.012981216
chr1_45797750_C_T   0.024949931
chr19_9002576_T_C
chr19_9018540_A_G
```

And to pretty-print:

```
$ ( printf '%-20s\t%s\n' "id" "freq_var"; join -t$'\t' -a1 -j1 <(tail -n+2 fileA.txt | sort)  <(tail -n+2 fileB.txt | sort))
id                      freq_var
chr1_45796849_A_T   0.028399811
chr1_45796852_G_C   0.019154034
chr1_45796854_C_T   0.015872901
chr1_45797153_A_T   0.010129176
chr1_45797174_T_A
chr1_45797487_A_G   0.012981216
chr1_45797750_C_T   0.024949931
chr19_9002576_T_C
chr19_9018540_A_G
```

Comment: For those who always struggle with head/tail, the `tail -n+2` in this answer is equivalent to `sed 1d`

Answer (score 3):

```c
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    map[(NR>1 ? $1 : "id")] = $2
    next
}
{ print $1, map[$1] }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk fileB fileA
id  freq.var
chr1_45796849_A_T   0.028399811
chr1_45796854_C_T   0.015872901
chr1_45797174_T_A
chr1_45796852_G_C   0.019154034
chr19_9018540_A_G
chr19_9002576_T_C
chr1_45797487_A_G   0.012981216
chr1_45797153_A_T   0.010129176
chr1_45797750_C_T   0.024949931
```

Answer (score 1):

How about not using bash essentials, but something more comfortable like SQL (backed by a tool like [q](http://harelba.github.io/q/))?

```
q -H -O -t 'SELECT id, `freq.var` FROM fileA.txt as a LEFT OUTER JOIN fileB.txt as b ON a.id = b.chr_pos'
```

Answer (score 0):

**GNU sed** with extended regexp mode ON `-E` and no autoprint `-n`. Read in the fileB first and store it in hold space.
Then for every line of file A compare if it is found in hold.

```
sed -En '
  1{
    s/^\S+/id/
    :filea
      H;n
    /\t/b filea
    x;s/$/\n/;x
  }
  G
  s/^([^\n]+)\n.*\n(\1\t[^\n]*)\n.*/\2/p;t
  s/\n.*/\t/p
' fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

**Result:**

```
id  freq.var
chr1_45796849_A_T   0.028399811
chr1_45796854_C_T   0.015872901
chr1_45797174_T_A   
chr1_45796852_G_C   0.019154034
chr19_9018540_A_G   
chr19_9002576_T_C   
chr1_45797487_A_G   0.012981216
chr1_45797153_A_T   0.010129176
chr1_45797750_C_T   0.024949931
```